# Switching to a new window opened by a parent window that closes immediately

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium (new to java) and I'm having problems switching from one window to another.

the behavior of this IE system I am testing is once a button is clicked, it opens a new window and closes the old one immediately. Most of the guides I found on google involves multiple windows that are simultaneously open but this is not the case.

I have tried the following code:

```
String winhandlenew = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(winhandlenew);
```

by my understanding I don't need recursive codes as I don't have a parent window to switch back to (closes immediately after the new window is opened) so I just used a simple switchto command

the commands themselves do not give any error but as i progress, every element on that new window cannot be found. So, basically I have no clue if I'm switching correctly or if there is still a need to switch.

I would also like to note that both the parent window and child window have the same title.

Comment: `every element on that new window cannot be found` - maybe you need to wait for the other window to finish loading?

Comment: I tried adding an implicit wait of 10 seconds but still not working. Let me paste parts of the code if it helps. Please note that my way of coding is just based off tutorials, so bear with me :)

 
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class=\"BUTTONMIDDLE\"]")).click(); //this opens up the new window
       
String winhandlenew = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(winhandlenew);
       
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"username_input\"]")).sendKeys("USERNAME01");`

Comment: Instead of implicitly waiting, why not wait for one of the elements that you're looking for? Something like `driver.manage().timeouts().wait(..., <seconds you think page loads in>)`. By the way, your syntax looks like you're using the JS webdriver but your question has c# tagged.

Comment: If you're using JS webdriver, the wait function would look like: `...wait(function(){ return driver.isElementPresent(...);}, timeout)`. For C#, the syntax will be different but same concept will apply.

Comment: But as far as switching goes, is my code for switching correct? I read somewhere that since the parent window immediately closes after the the new window is opened it is no longer recognized as its child window and more of a new instance. About the wait function once the element is present, I think i may have tried that before but let me look into that again. And sorry about the C# tag, I'm using JS webdriver.

Comment: Not sure about that one.

Comment: Hi, I tried the the wait function until the specific element is found and I got this error: `WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //input[@name="username_input"])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`